# OSX smb share not visible outside local network

Tags: osx-yosemite, smb

I am running a server on OSX 10.10 and want to share a folder with SMB. The server has a static IP (not private) connected to internet. Of course there are probabably a bunch of routers between.

Mounting the share with `AFP://` works fine on same network. Also `smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/share_name` from Macs and from Windows: `\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\share_name`. The problem is with SMB from outside this network. 
There is no problem connecting with AFP from the outside.

When I try to access `smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` from a Mac I get an error (Norwegian translated) "There was a problem connecting to the server xxxxxx. Maybe the server does not exist or is unavailable...."

Connecting from Windows 10 it just times out.

I read that there may be some ports that need mapping but I have no idea really. There must be someone who has tried this and succeeded!

Answer (score 1):

Over TCP you need to open the port 445 if you want to use NetBIOS then there are On UDP ports 137, 138 & TCP ports 137, 139 (NetBIOS over TCP/IP)

Comment: Thanks @sebastienvg. What do you mean by "need to open the port.." ? There is no firewall running on the server and I don't think it is behind a firewall. If I do this command in terminal `lsof -Pn -i4` I can not see these ports listen that you mention. From a machine on the servers network I can telnet port 445 but none of the other ports you mention answer. From outside not any of the ports answer.

Comment: What I mean is that you need to forward the port 445 from your router (the device that is actually connected to internet and holds the public_ip) to the IP of the machine running the service you want to expose (smb in this case)

Comment: So the server has a public IP (xx.xx.xx.33) (no private) and I need to direct port 445 from the outside to port 445 on the server (xx.xx.xx.33)? Do I understand? Will this affect any other machines if I want to share a folder on another server in the same network? I thought traffic to the server would hit the router and direct to 445 on the server, like port 80. But it doesn't?

Comment: I got this all wrong, I didn't pay attention that you mentioned using public IP on the server. Can you please confirm the network setup? How is the Mac connected to internet?

Comment: The mac is connected directly to the internett and has only 2 public IP addresses (since I have both http and https). This is at a university so I can ask the network guys to check if they are blocking port 443?

Comment: I wonder if it is not possible to share with SMB outside of local network. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345233/create-smb-server-in-order-to-share-files?rq=1): one writes: _From my experience, you can't connect to a SMB share outside of your local network. If you're trying to mount a SMB share, you'll have to use a VPN or other form of tunnel adapter to connect._  So are we at a dead end then and have to use other ways to share? I have heard of CIFS.

Comment: Well, I tried and it seems the link you mentioned is right, when I am able to use SMB over VPN and I wasn't able to make it work on public network.

Comment: I am looking now at [iVPN](http://macserve.org.uk/projects/ivpn/) but still have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: I had to open port 445 and 139 on the machine to make it work.

Comment: You got it to work over Internet without VPN?

Comment: No I didn't it only works within the LAN or over VPN for me. I am not sure if it's possible or not over internet but if it is I highly don't recommend it because of the lack of security.